# Migrating 'Handles' from VB.NET to C#

Tags: c#, vb.net, events, handles

I'm migrating some code from VB.NET to C# (3.5).

I find structures like:

```
Public Event DataLoaded(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

Protected Sub Mag_Button_Load_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Mag_Button_Load.Click
[..]
        RaiseEvent DataLoaded(Me, EventArgs.Empty)
End Sub
[..]

'Other Class
Private Sub LoadData(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles oData.DataLoaded
[..]
End Sub
```

What is the most straightforward way to translate such behaviour to C#?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I recommend using the [Telerik Code Converter](http://converter.telerik.com/) as a start.

C# does not have that easy automatic attaching of event handlers by means of the "Handles" keyword like VB.NET does.

```
//EventHandler declaration
public event EventHandler  DataLoaded;
protected void Mag_Button_Load_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    //Raise Event
    if (DataLoaded != null) {
        DataLoaded(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

Also, You need to assign your event handlers to the objects like this:

```
Button1.Click += Button1_Click;

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  //do something.
}
```

However C# does have the succinct ability of doing this as well:

```
Button1.Click += (sender, e)=>
{
    //do something
}
```

Comment: I think you've either forgotten the => for a lambda expression in the last piece of code (or the delegate keyword and parameter types for an anonymous method).

Comment: Adding lambda expressions to events can be done in VB.NET as well, with the following monstrosity: `AddHandler Button1.Click, Sub (sender,e) 'do something here`, or `AddHandler Button1.Click, Sub (sender,e) 'do something here over multiple lines' End Sub`