# What is the difference between events in VB and C#?

Tags: c#, vb.net, events

I am a VB programmer working my way into C#. I learned how to create and raise events in vb and am finding that it isnt done the same way in C#. Has anybody come across an article that will help me to understand how to do events in C# and maybe explain why it is different in VB.

Thanks

Comment: This question explains the difference between `handles` in VB.Net and C# event syntax http://stackoverflow.com/questions/794332/migrating-handles-from-vb-net-to-c

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Does this help?

[VB.NET vs. C# - Delegates / Events](http://www.harding.edu/fmccown/vbnet_csharp_comparison.html#delegatesandevents)

Answer (score 1):

The main difference is the syntax that's used.  Underneath, they use the exact same mechanisms within the CLR.

However, VB.NET provides special syntax via `WithEvents` and `Handles`, allowing you to do:

```
Dim WithEvents button1 As Button

Private Sub button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyButton.Click 
    ' Handle button click
End Sub
```

C# doesn't provide an equivelent - all events must be explicitly subscribed to via `event +=`, which is more like VB.NET's `AddHandler` statement.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is mostly syntactic.

See [this](http://www.harding.edu/fmccown/vbnet_csharp_comparison.html#delegatesandevents) handy reference about the differences.

The event handler in VB.NET is declared with the `Handling` key word appended to the event handler signature. In C# you need to use register it with `+=`.

In VB.NET you invoke the event with `RaiseEvent`, in C# you call the delegate directly.

Answer (score 0):

Reading from:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739(VS.71).aspx

> An event in C# is a way for a class to
>   provide notifications to clients of
>   that class when some interesting thing
>   happens to an object. The most
>   familiar use for events is in
>   graphical user interfaces; typically,
>   the classes that represent controls in
>   the interface have events that are
>   notified when the user does something
>   to the control (for example, click a
>   button).
>
> Events, however, need not be used only
>   for graphical interfaces. Events
>   provide a generally useful way for
>   objects to signal state changes that
>   may be useful to clients of that
>   object. Events are an important
>   building block for creating classes
>   that can be reused in a large number
>   of different programs.

Refer to the article for the rest.

Answer (score 0):

A good quick general reference for some key differences in syntax can be found [here](http://www.harding.edu/fmccown/vbnet_csharp_comparison.html).  Search for "events" to get to that section.

Key differences is that VB requires you to use some keywords rather than addition/subtraction to wire up events, but gives you a *handles* keyword automatically wire a routine to an event.  And when passing a delegate, you must use a pointless AddressOf keyword.  (Sorry for the editorial, but I think that keyword causes more confusion than it saves!)