# Code snippets shortkey in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, keyboard-shortcuts, code-snippets

Is there a way in VB.NET to replicate C# behavior on code snippets in case of capturing events?

I.E.
in C#:

```
Btn.Click+=
```

and then double-tab. Creates an handler for btn.click event.

Comment: may sound stupid but often it works for events documented online: google it and copy/paste handler declaration from examples. I know, this doesn't answer the question, but is better than hovering the event member to hardly read its tooltip, and becomes an easy workaround for things like  `dte.Events.CommandEvents.BeforeExecute`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C# you can only connect events explicitly, using `+=`. The VB equivalent is `AddHandler`.

But VB also lets you [connect events implicitly using the `Handles` keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2547033/what-is-the-difference-between-events-in-vb-and-c/2547083#2547083). Notice that VB event handling is more flexible than C#.

There are several ways to automatically create event handler code using `Handles`.

1. In design-view, just double-click the button.
2. Or, in design-view again:

   a. In the button's properties window, click the "lightning bolt" to view events.

   b. Double-click the `Click` event.
3. Or, in code view, you can use the two drop-downs at the top of the window

   a. Select the button in the left-hand one.

   b. Select the `Click` event in the right-hand one.

**EDIT**: in VB.Net 2010 you can handle events with [statement lambdas](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee336123.aspx). Example:

```
AddHandler b.Click, _
  Sub(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    MsgBox("Button Clicked")
    'insert more complex logic here
   End Sub
```

OK, so maybe you know about implicit event handling *and* anonymous methods, and you've still decided you really need to wire up explicit local methods from `AddHandler` all the time. Maybe there's a third-party add-in that supports it. Maybe [CodeRush](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/Visual_Studio_Add-in/Coding_Assistance/Templates.xml) does, I don't know (if anyone knows please leave a comment). Or you could even create your own add-in.

Comment: I'll choose from the list. It seems like I forgot all my horrible VB6 skills... I'm too spoiled now.

Answer (score 3):

Strangely enough the VB.NET team didn't implement such feature in Visual Studio.

Comment: @Frauz, I understand your frustration :-)

Comment: @Faruz, @Darin. There's no shortcut for explicitly connecting events. But in VB it's more common to [connect events implicitly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2547033/what-is-the-difference-between-events-in-vb-and-c/2547083#2547083). Which is probably why there are no shortcuts for the explicit method. [My answer lists some shortcuts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4182177/code-snippets-shortkey-in-vb-net/4183940#4183940) for the implicit method.

Comment: @Faruz, @Darin. The better you understand *any* language, the less frustrating it will be. There are only a [few differences](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/columns/article.aspx?editorialsid=2894) between C# and VB, and they are [easily learnt](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1337253/15639).

Comment: @MarkJ, the implicit way of handling events in VB.NET can be applied only to some global variables. What if you had a local variable and you wanted to apply an event handler. You would need to do it explicitly, by declaring the method body first and then wiring it up while in C# it's just a matter of double Tab. I am not an expert in VB.NET, I just have some general culture but personally prefer C# :-) Don't want to start flame wars though.

Comment: @Darin Implicit event handling can be applied to module-level variables as well as globals: the classic examples are controls created by drawing in the forms designer. I think it might be uncommon to want to wire a local variable's event to a new explicit method. When you have a local variable, typically isn't it better to create a lambda? If local variable->explicit method really is needed frequently, it might be worth checking whether CodeRush supports it.

Comment: @MarkJ, indeed you are correct. Local variables work better with anonymous functions.