# Equivalent in C# to "Handles" in VB.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have this code in Visual Basic, and it works when I test it. All the rows have alternate colors.

```
Private Sub GridView1_RowCreated(ByVal sender As Object, _
                                 ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) _
                                 Handles GridView1.RowDataBound
    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
        Dim RowNum as Integer
        RowNum = e.Row.RowIndex

        If RowNum mod 2 = 1 Then
            e.Row.Attributes.Add("onmouseout", "this.style.backgroundColor='#DDDDDD'")
        Else
            e.Row.Attributes.Add("onmouseout", "this.style.backgroundColor='#FFFFFF'")
        End If

        e.Row.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "this.style.backgroundColor='DeepSkyBlue'")
        e.Row.Attributes("onclick") = Me.Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(Me.GridView1, "Select$" & e.Row.RowIndex)
    End If
End Sub
```

Since I am working under C# enviroment, I converted it to C#:

```
private void GridView1_RowCreated(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        int RowNum = e.Row.RowIndex;
        if (RowNum % 2 == 1)
        {
            e.Row.Attributes.Add("onmouseout", "this.style.backgroundColor='#DDDDDD'");
        }
        else
        {
            e.Row.Attributes.Add("onmouseout", "this.style.backgroundColor='#FFFFFF'");
        }

        e.Row.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "this.style.backgroundColor='DeepSkyBlue'");
        e.Row.Attributes["onclick"] = this.Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(this.GridView1, "Select$" + e.Row.RowIndex);
    }
}
```

Is that a way I can do same as "Handles" option in Visual Basic? Please provide me the code if possible.

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/794332/migrating-handles-from-vb-net-to-c-sharp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to add the event handler either from markup

```
<asp:GridView OnRowCreated="GridView1_RowCreated" runat="server" ID="MyGrid">

</asp:GridView>
```

or from code-behind

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   MyGrid.RowCreated += GridView1_RowCreated;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to add the handler in Page_Load() like this:

```
Protected Void Page_Load(Object Sender, EventArgs e){
    GridView1.RowCreated += GridView1_RowCreated;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try with

```
GridView1.RowCreated += GridView1_RowCreated;
```

Nota : I suggest you to initialize your delegate in `Page_Init` (Best Practise)

Comment: I add this code "GridView1.RowCreated += GridView1_RowCreated;" from everyone suggested to Page_Load, it works with alternating color for rows after the page loaded, but when I click on a row, it changes all row backcolor to white.  So I try to put in it Page_Int, it works better. What is "Best Pracise" about Page_Init? please advise.  Thanks

Comment: Always happy to help you, In your page Init you set all your registering of delegate, you can also find  user control in page aspx, in order to pass arguments Milacay

Answer (score 1):

C# as a language doesn't have a concept like the "handles" keyword.
Instead, you must explicitly wire-up event definitions.

Try

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.RowCreated += GridView1_RowCreated;
}
```

C# adds handlers by '+=' operator and remove them by '-=' operator.

Even in VB.NET you can skip "handles" if you use AutoEventWireUp="true".