# Events written in .cs page are not fired after converting project from VB.Net to C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, migration

I have converted a large sized ASp.Net Web forms project from VB.Net to C# using [SharpDevelop](https://github.com/icsharpcode/CodeConverter) and have been able to compile the project after fixing all errors(2100 in my case to be precise).

When I execute the code, I notice that the .aspx page works fine however, none of the events that converted to .cs file from .vb file is getting fired. For ex - `Page_Load / btn_click` etc. I have changed the event handler definitions from `Private void Function()` to `protected void Function()` but still same problems. Can someone advise on how to resolve the same?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you convert the handlers from vb.net style to C# style? C# doesn't have a handles clause, so you would need to convert that to use delegates and then register them as the handler for the events. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/794332/migrating-handles-from-vb-net-to-c-sharp for more information.

Answer (score 1):

In `VB.Net` the events are attached inlined on event handler method signature. 
e.g.

```
YoueventHandler(object, sender) Handles button1.Click
```

When you convert `vb.net` code to `C#` using any converters, the handler is converted but event handler registration will be gone. You have to re-register these eventhandler with the events in C#.

Here's Linqpad script that will help you scan a VB file for events and generate the C# handler for it.

```
void Main()
{
    var file = @"youcodeFile.vb";
    Regex r = new Regex(@"Sub (?<evthandler>[\S]+)\(.*\)\s?Handles\s?(?<eventName>[\S]+)");
    var events = r.Matches(File.ReadAllText(file)).Cast<Match>().Select(x => new { Event = x.Groups["eventName"].Value, Handler = x.Groups["evthandler"].Value});
    events.Dump();

    events.Select(x => $"{x.Event} += {x.Handler};").Dump();
}
```

Scanned events:

[image]

C# Output :

```
Me.Load += frmOutlookSyncStatus_Load; 
btnGo.Click += BtnGo_Click; 
btnLookupCase.Click += BtnLookupCase_Click; 
RepositoryItemButtonEdit1.Click += RepositoryItemButtonEdit1_Click; 
GridView1.CustomRowCellEdit += GridView1_CustomRowCellEdit; 
GridView1.CustomUnboundColumnData += gridViewEvents_CustomUnboundColumnData;
```